# How to pass arguments when using Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

I want to pass a `bool` argument while using Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/screen', ModalRoute.withName('/screen'));
```

Can we do it? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/screen', ModalRoute.withName('/screen'), arguments: boolValue);

Answer (score 0):

As @camillo777 said this is possible.
You can pass and retrieve arguments passed by a named route: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments